# Can not display double quotes when saving to database

Tags: php

I am saving double quotes that need to be saved in the database, then later shown on the screen.

```
$in = '2" to 2.33"';
$in = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $in);
echo $in; // Shows with backslashes
$results = $db->query("UPDATE store_item_brims SET BrimSizeIn='$in' WHERE ID=2");

// Later I query the database and load to an array
// print_r of the array shows with no backslashes
// echoing into text input field does not work
```

When I view the data in PHPMyAdmin, it saves in the database without any visible backslashes. When I load the data to an array and `print_r` the array, it is shown in the array. However, when I try to echo it out in an input text field for the user to update, it only shows `2` and cuts off as soon as the first double quote is reached.

How do I fix this?

Comment: Click view source (not inspect element) what do you see

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you echo it in to a HTML input the quotes mess up the quotes the HTML input uses as deliminators so short answer:

```
<input type="text" value="<?php echo htmlentities($YOUR_VALUE); ?>" ...
```

reference: [htmlentities](http://php.net/htmlentities)